# How can i check all value in the array equal to a certain number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have textboxes with the same class name. I have a requirement that Receipt Number must be 12 alpha numeric character as `aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa` format. How can I check or validate all of the textbox value length equal 12 characters?

I tried the following code but I need help checking all the values in the array `receiptNumberLenArr` array equal to 12 otherwise display validation error

```
       var receiptNumberLenArr= [];
       var txtReceiptNumber = $(".k-maskedtextbox .txtReceiptNumber");
       var txtReceiptNumberLen = $(txtReceiptNumber).length;

        for (var i = 0; i < txtReceiptNumberLen; i++) {
            var inputVal = $(txtReceiptNumber[i]).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '');
            var inputCountLen = inputVal.length
            receiptNumberLenArr.push(inputCountLen);
        }
```

Comment: You can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check all textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array.every, it synax like:

```
array.every(function(elm, index) { return checkResult })
```